# How to prove that $a_{2n} = a_nb_n$ in a Lucas sequence?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction, fibonacci-numbers, lucas-numbers

Here's the question in in my book:

Define $(b_n)$ by $b_1=1$, $b_n = a_{n+1}+a_{n-1}$ for $n ≥ 2$. $(b_n)$ is known as the sequence of Lucas numbers.

Prove

(i) $b_n = b_{n-1} + b_{n-2}$ for $n ≥ 3$.

(ii) $a_{2n} = a_nb_n$.

where $(a_n)$ is the Fibonacci sequence of numbers.

I was able to prove the first part but was unable to prove the second using mathematical induction. I tried very hard but couldn't solve it. Kindly suggest a way to prove this.

*If you have any proof other than induction, then please do share it as it would be very helpful to know other methods too.*

Comment: You can check [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/267309/fibonacci-lucas-numbers-relationship-f-2n-f-n-l-n?rq=1).

Comment: @SacAndSac Thanks.