# Proving $F_2n = F_n L_n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have seen this question posted somewhere on this site before, but they included a lemma in which
$$_{2−1}=F^2_+F^2_{−1}$$
This wasn't demonstrated to me through my textbook, and I was asked to prove the same question. So I am curious if there is another way to prove this question without such a lemma. I tried relating the $F_{2n}$ term without this lemma but failed, so I want to know whether or not this is possible without that lemma.

I am very new to number theory, so in addition to this question, can I get some advice on how to improve in this field of mathematics and how should I spot which lemma or theorems are needed for a question?

Comment: Does [https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/267309/fibonacci-lucas-numbers-relationship-f-2n-f-n-l-n?rq=1](this MSE answer) help you out?

Comment: sorry, i was looking at a different article on MSE, haha well thanks so much man appreciate it